# Orthogonal complement in Hilbert space

Tags: proof-verification, hilbert-spaces

Let $\,  M := \{ x \in H : L(x) = 0 \}$  where $H$ is a Hilbert Space and $L$ $ \in H^* : L \neq 0 $ . Prove that $ M^\perp$ is a one dimensional space.

$\textbf{Here is my attempt:}$

Fix $L \in H^*$ then we can assume that $\exists! \, w \in H : L(x) = \, \langle \, x \, , \, w \, \rangle $ and so we can rewrite $M$ as $\{ x \in H : \langle \, x \, , \, w \, \rangle  = 0 \} $. From the definition of $M^\perp$ it seems to me trivial that $M^\perp = \{ w\}$.

Am i wrong somewhere? If yes, could you give me some hints?

Comment: It is indee trivial that $\text{Span}(w) \subset M^\bot$, but the other inclusion need some kind of proof/argument

Comment: Your proof is correct. Incidentally the kernel of a non-zero continuous linear functional has co-dimension 1 in any normed linear space.